# clarification on train, test and val and how to use/implement it

Tags: keras, training, cross-validation, prediction

So far I think I understood the differences between the training, test and validation set. Basically it is like in this image:

[image: Overview]

**Training set:** The data where the model is trained on

**Validation set:** Data the model has not been trained on and used to tune hyperparameters

**Test set:** In principle the same like the validation set.. just used at the final end after the model has been tailored.

The training set is usually set up via some [cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection). When fitting via `model.fit(X_train, y_train,..)` will Keras shuffle the data autonomously ?

Next, in Keras, you are able to provide the validation set inside the `model.fit()` method as `validation_data=(x_test, y_test)` but there is also the possibility to provide e.g. `validation_split = 0.2`
What is the difference?

And after that, the test/prediction set will be taken into account just as `model.pred(X_pred, y_pred,..)`. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When fitting via `model.fit(X_train, y_train,..)`, will Keras shuffle the
data autonomously?**

Yes. `shuffle = True` is default. So, it basically shuffles every time.

---

**Next, in Keras, you are able to provide the validation set inside the `model.fit()` method as `validation_data=(x_test, y_test)` but there is also the possibility to provide e.g. `validation_split = 0.2` What is the difference?**

The difference is that you can manually provide a validation data set. It's not `X_test`, `Y_test`. Rather `X_test` and `Y_test` are used for model evaluation `model.evaluate()` or `model.predict()`. `model.fit` is used for the training dataset. When you say `validation_set = 0.2`, it takes 20% data from training dataset and provides you the validation accuracy and loss.

---

**And after that, the test/prediction set will be taken into account just as `model.fit(X_pred, y_pred,..)`. Right?**

You need to use `model.predict(X_pred, Y_pred)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Some more questions: E.g. on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263117/cross-validation-with-sklearn-in-keras the CV resp. the fitting is done within a for loop. How does Keras know in "model.fit()" which folds it has to use when it is not done inside a loop? Then: using "validation_set" instead of a separate data set is recommendable? And "model.evaluate()" is not necessary in this case, right?

Comment: Keras basically knows it by 'for loop'. I think the code in link you mentioned is not correct. When you use K-fold cross-validation, K-1 folds will be used for training and some portion can be used for validation. The last fold should be used for testing.

Comment: Thanks, so this means I have to fit the model within a for-loop?

Comment: You can use train-test- validation split (say 60% train, 20% validation and 20% test.) when you have large dataset. In that case you dont need to use for loop. For smaller dataset normally K-fold is used and in that case for loop can be applied. If  you find this answer satisfactory, please don forget to mark right. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, for a better understanding: When using train_test_split() I don't need a for loop but when using KFold() I do? Here on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html they use the latter within a for loop..?

Comment: Yes. train_test_split(), you should not use a loop because you have one set of training and one set of testing data. But in Kfold(), say you use k = 5 that is means 5 fold cross-validation. In this case, you will get 5 equal set of data from where you want to use 4 set as tarining and the rest for tseting. Iterate this process for other set also.    https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-cross-validate-a-model-d6424b45261f. This post will help you to understand the cross-validation technique